# Linear Search on Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, testing, search, vector

I have tests to pass online using my created methods. I have a feeling there is an issue with one of the tests. The final one i cannot pass. 
Here is the test-

```
TEST_CASE ("Linear Search With Self-Organization 3") {
  int searchKey = 191;

  vector<int> searchArray(500);
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    searchArray[i] = i + 1;
  }
  random_shuffle(searchArray.begin(), searchArray.end());

  bool result, result2;
  result = linearSearchSO(searchArray, searchKey);
  int searchKey2 = 243;
  result2 = linearSearchSO(searchArray, searchKey2);

  REQUIRE (result == true);
  REQUIRE (result2 == true);
  REQUIRE (verifySearchArray(searchArray) == true);
  REQUIRE (searchArray[0] == searchKey2);
  REQUIRE (searchArray[1] == searchKey);
  REQUIRE (searchArray.size() == 500);
}
```

The method in question here is linearSearchSO.

```
bool linearSearchSO(vector<int> & inputArr, int searchKey) {
   printArray(inputArr);
   for(int i=0; i < inputArr.size(); i++) {
      int temp = inputArr[0];
      if (inputArr[i] == searchKey) {
         inputArr[0] = inputArr[i];
         inputArr[i] = temp;
         printArray(inputArr);
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false; 
}
```

Worth noting that this method has passed all 3 of the other tests required. As you can see in the test, my tutor has called this method twice passing two different values.The idea is that there is a vector of 500 numbers.. In this instance he randomises the numbers. The best way for me to explain what is happening is that if he didn't randomise and the numbers were simply listed 1-500. The method gets called and I begin with the requested number 191, I move this to front of the vector. 
Now it reads 191, 2, 3, 4 etc. 190, 1, 192 etc.
So he then calls the method again, and wants 243 to be moved to the front. His test wants the result to be 243, 191, 2, 3, 4. However what my code does is swap 191 to 243's position. 
My result now reads 243, 2, 3, 4 etc. 242, 191, 244, 245 etc.

Every other test is simply taking one number and moving it to the front, the test then checks that each number is in the correct position. My question is, is there a way for me to achieve 243, 191, 2, 3.. without messing up every other test I've passed only using this one linearSearch function? or is there a problem with the test, and hes simply made a mistake.

EDIT- The actual question asked for this test. 
Question 4
A self-organising search algorithm is one that rearranges items in a collection such that those items that are searched frequently are likely to be found sooner in the search. Modify the learning algorithm for linear search such that every time an item is found in the array, that item is exchanged with the item at the beginning of the array.

Comment: You want to know how to remove an element from a position in a `vector` while retaining all other elements' order. And you want to know how to insert an element at the front of a `vector`. Is that correct?

Comment: Please: put in some effort and fix the indentation in your post. You're asking for our time and the benefit of our experience. The least you can do is format your post.

Comment: Hi John, I actually have achieved that part. My method allows me to move an element from a position in a vector while retaining all other elements' order and also insert the element to the front. My problem is with the method being called twice in the test, after the first call '191' is now at vector position 0. So upon second call the method will swap 191 as I've set temp to the vector position 0, where as the test result wants 243 to become vector position 0, and 191 vector position 1... Sorry 3Dave, we're using Repl.it and it doesn't do automatic indentation.

Comment: @soupyc123 Your function swaps the chosen element with the first element in the array. Always. In your example when you find `191`, you swap it with `1`. That is NOT preserving the order of all other elements. Not the first time you call the function, not the 100th time you call the function. If your function did a removal and an insertion, you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: According to the problem statement: "...such that every time an item is found in the array, that item is exchanged with the item at the beginning of the array." your algorithm is working. It's the test case that doesn't match if the test case is failing.

Comment: I edited the question I have asked, I understand that there are alternative ways to do this, but its what we've been asked to do. I have been specifically told to use a Linear Search, and exchange the two items. This is why I have asked if the mistake could be on his side.

Comment: *I have been specifically told to use a Linear Search* -- You could have used `std::find`, which is a linear search, and then `std::swap` to swap items.  If you did that, then your actual code would say exactly what you're doing, `std::find`-ing, and then `std::swap`-ping.  You would then have little to no reason why your code would not be following the instructions given, and the onus would be on your tutor.

Comment: @soupyc123 Tell him to change the wording to "..such that every time an item is found in the array, that item is removed from its current position and inserted at the front of the array, while preserving the order of all other elements." if that's what he wants

Comment: I will email the tutor, thanks John.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would if i could, but we're not allowed to. The point of the assignment is to learn how to create a method replicating the Linear Search, without the use of library functions.

Comment: @soupyc123 The point of first using library functions is to quickly prototype your idea of how things would work.  If you get the library function version working, then switch to writing those functions by hand.  For example, you could have written the library version first, and then taken just the *output* to the tutor to confirm the output is correct.  Then go back and rewrite your code with the confidence that you actually know what the output would look like, plus you have a good outline of what to replace in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly you need something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool linearSearchSO( std::vector<int> & inputArr, int searchKey ) 
{
    bool success = false;

    auto it = inputArr.begin();

    while  (  it != inputArr.end() && *it != searchKey ) ++it;

    if ( ( success = it != inputArr.end() ) )
    {
        int value = *it;
        inputArr.erase( it );
        inputArr.insert( inputArr.begin(), value );
    }

    return success;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> inputArr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for ( const auto &item : inputArr )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    linearSearchSO( inputArr, 3 );   

    for ( const auto &item : inputArr )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 
3 1 2 4 5
```

Pay attention to that instead of writing manually a loop in the function you could use the standard algorithm `std::find`.